# How to align a shopping cart which can have only one item at a time?

Tags: layout, shopping-cart

We are designing the interface for our shopping cart. More precisely, we call it register page which is used for registering one course at a time.

However, we ran into a little disagreement in organizing its layout. Below are the two versions which we are considering.

So here are the things that concern me:

- **Label aligning**: From some online resources, I have learned that right-align would be a better choice (version 2). So version 2 has this and centered sections except for the first section. However, someone said right-aligned label would break whole page alignment. All sections must be aligned the same style (center or left align).
- **Page layout**: In version 1, each section is vertically organized separated by a light-colored horizontal bar. In version 2, the two middle sections are set side by side.

Could you please tell me which version you like better?

If you have time, please help me analyze further details.

What do you think of the two version in term of **Label aligning**, **Page layout**? Which would make a better choice or is there any other option?

Is it true about the thing all sections must be aligned the same style?
Does the version 1 or version 2 look unbalance?

What improvements can be made to version 1 (or version 2)?

**Version 1**
[image: version1]

**Version 2**
[image: version2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have them use numeric steps. And don't use drop-downs when they select their state. Common problem. Just have them type the two letters.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8nfWq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Center sucks. Align left or right.

I liked it better when each section had 100% width. Don't have a good design guideline to rationalize this feeling.

I like your designs. For the second sketch, maybe stack both input boxes in the first section, instead of placing them in-line with lots of whitespace. People scan the page from the top left downward. Stacking might prevent users from missing the box. Using AJAX will update the text without requiring the user to click.

One more thing I caught. If you're going to use horizontal rules for each section, maybe include a header to explain why it's sectioned off? Example:

---

stuff that's *not cool*

---

### Heading

stuff that's way cooler with that heading up there

---